# Running SQL Stored Procedure process without stopping on errors

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know a good pattern to execute a stored procedure that I don't want to be stopped when an error occurs.

For example I have an Employee table and a process that has to send one email for each Employee every month. Before send the email, I need to validate some data and do some insert/update for each employee. Ones everything is correct, I send the email, then the same process for the second Employee and so on...

If one of the Employee has something wrong, I don't want to stop the all process, I just need to put the Employee Id in another table for example and continue with the process until finish the 100 Employees.

Whats the best approach for this. I didn't do any stored procedure yet, I just need a mock up of how to do it to be sure that is not going to stop when an error occurs.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you want to use ? Do you want to have the whole logic in SQL ?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the logic in SQL, then you can have a loop and in the loop

```
while Condition until all employees are processed
begin

begin try 
...
end try 
begin catch 
...
end catch

end
```

Comment: ok perfect, if I need a transaction I'll put it inside the try section to control each employee process